# run java jar in aws Lambda with error com/google/gson/JsonElement: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, aws-lambda, gson

I am trying to run a java jar in aws lambda,
the jar is trying to perform a HTTP Get request and get data from some endpoint, however I get this error and I can't figure out the problem.

```
com/google/gson/JsonElement: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.ClassNot.forName(Unknown Source)
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.gson.Jsonelement
   at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And how did you create the JAR? It seems you didn't include Gson classes in it

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: You don't include Gson dependency. Also, do you use proguard which might remove Gson

Answer (score 0):

You miss the gson library inn your classpath. Add it and the error should gone.

If you are using maven you can add the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have the dependency added, thats not the issue !

Comment: I have added it to the pom.xml file under dependencies

Comment: under `dependencyManagement`? Which scope? Can you add your pom to your question please?

Comment: what do you mean which scope?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html compile, test, runtime, provided

Comment: @Jesn the problem is not from the gson the problem I believe when the lambda make the request and the Get request comes back, it can't accept the response for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205743/discussion-between-jens-and-marwan-bshara).

Comment: After reading egain i am a little confused why the `e` in `Jsonelement``  in caused by is lower case

Answer (score 0):

as @cricket_007 mentioned, you need to include the gson jar file.

if you are using maven, you need to add the gson dependency.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the dependency added!